# Security Query for the Users ina SharePoint Site

Tags: security, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am updating a SharePoint 2007 solution to SharePoint 2013. The solution creates a list of permissions for each site in a site collection. In SharePoint 2007 I used SOAP to query the ROLE object and got back the Groups and Users security objects for a site. In SharePoint 2013 ROLE and SOAP is deprecated. I am trying to use the REST API to recreate the solution. I am able to get the groups object for each site, but I am unable to find the way to get the Users security object for the sites. I can get Site Users for the site collection and get the Users in a SharePoint Group, but I find no way to get the Users Security Object for a site. Has anyone been able to accomplish get the Users for a site?

Answer (score 0):

Sample REST api to check user permission for site.

You need encode the URL from(suppose your use default NTLM authentication)

```
/_api/web/getusereffectivepermissions(@user)?@user='i:0#.w|contoso\userb'
```

TO

```
/_api/web/getusereffectivepermissions(@user)?@user='i%3A0%23.w%7Ccontoso%5Cuserb'
```

About the return value, check below thread.

http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/checking-user-permissions-from-the-sharepoint-2013-rest-api/?doing_wp_cron=1449727796.2080190181732177734375